Onsen UI global method setDefaultDeviceBackButtonListener only working on the lowest page in the pagestack
I'm currently using Onsen UI (Version 2nd) to develop a mobile app.
I need to register a certain method to let it fire when the device back button is pushed.
I tried using setDefaultDeviceBackButtonListener, a global method of Onsen UI (the use of the method is self-explanatory), on one of upper pages on the pagestack, only to find it fired when the current page is the only page the pagestack contains.
ons.setDefaultDeviceBackButtonListener(()=>{
    //blah blah
})

Is it always the case or can that be changed? If the latter is the case, how? I'd appreciate your answer.
